Prove that finite intersection of open sets is open using open rectangles
Consider a finite collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$. I want to prove that $I:=\bigcap_{i=1}^mS_i$ is open.
I know how to prove this statement using open balls. You take an element $x\in I$, then $x\in S_i$ for all $i$, and since $S_i$ is open for all $i$, then for all $i$, there exists $r_i>0$ such that $B(x,r_i)\subset S_i$. Then you can define $r_0$ to be the minimum of all the $r_i$. Then clearly $B(x,r_0)\subset B(x,r_i)$ for all $i$. So $B(x,r_0)\subset I$.
Now, I want to prove this using open rectangles.
So, if $x\in I$, then $x\in S_i$ for all $i$. Since each $S_i$ is open, for all $i$ there exists an open rectangle $R_i$ such that $x\in R_i\subset S_i$.
But I'm clueless after this step. How can I define certain $R_0$ in such a way that $R_0\subset I$?
I thought about perhaps defining $R_0$ to be the $R_i$ with smallest diameter or something similar, but I don't like this idea since the diameter of a set was defined after this exercise. So it doesn't make sense to use a tool that was introduced later in order to solve a problem that was presented earlier

you can fit balls inside rectangles and vice-versa

You could also do induction over the dimension $n$.

You can define the rectangles as follows:
If you denote $x = (x_i)_{i=1}^n$. As $x \in S_i$, with $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}$, then $\exists \epsilon_{i_1}, \dots, \epsilon_{i_n} > 0$, such that $]x_1-\epsilon_{i_1}, x_1+\epsilon_{i_1}[\times\dots\times]x_n-\epsilon_{i_n}, x_n+\epsilon_{i_n}[ \subseteq S_i$. Therefore, $]x_1-\min\{\epsilon_{i_1} : i \in \{1, \dots, m\}\}, x_1+\min\{\epsilon_{i_1} : i \in \{1, \dots, m\}\}[\times\dots\times]x_n-\min\{\epsilon_{i_n} : i \in \{1, \dots, m\}\}, x_n+\min\{\epsilon_{i_n} : i \in \{1, \dots, m\}\}[ \subseteq I$.
A different way to prove that $I$ is open is the following one: By the definition of topology and open set, you can prove it by induction over $m$ (the amount of terms in the intersection).
